# "Deselecting" a button using textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm new to flutter and I am making a list of choices. The first 4 are multiple choice, and the 5th one is an "open-ended" where users can enter text. I want to be able to make sure that the user can only select one of these options. For the last option, if they start typing, it will be selected. However, if they click elsewhere, all the text will be cleared. I got it working for the multiple choice but I'm not sure what I can do for the fifth option. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is what I have for the first four multiple choice:

```
  Widget buildChoices(Choice choice, double buttonHeight) {
    return buildMultipleChoice(
      choice: choice,
      onClicked: () {
        setState(() {
          for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            if (choices[i] != choice) {
              choices[i].isSelected = false;
            }
          }
          choice.isSelected = !choice.isSelected;
        });
      },
      buttonHeight: buttonHeight,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a TextField widget and set the onChanged property to a function that select the specific choice, therefore unselecting all the other ones.